# What is a complex constant and how do I use it?

Tags: complex-numbers, definition, quadratics

I have a question I am trying to understand:
"Let $b$ and $c$ be complex constants such that $z^2+bz+c=0$ has two different real roots.  Show that $b$ and $c$ are real."

My biggest problem here is that I don't know what a complex constant is; I have tried to google it, however all I am getting for results is computer programming information, which I am finding unhelpful.  Could someone please explain to me what exactly this is and how I can use it to solve the above problem?

Comment: that means that $b$ and $c$ are fixed complex numbers, independent of $z$.

Comment: Complex constant just means [complex number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) in this context.

Comment: $b=b_1+ib_2, c=c_1+ic_2. b_1,b_2,c_1,c_2 \in \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Hint from *Semiclassical* with the two real roots $r_1 \neq r_2$:
\begin{align}
r_1^2+r_1(b_1 +ib_2) + (c_1 + ic_2) &= 0\\
r_2^2+r_2(b_1 +ib_2) + (c_1 + ic_2) &= 0
\end{align}

Summing up the imaginary parts

\begin{align}
i(r_1b_2 + c_2) &= 0\\
i(r_2b_2 + c_2) &= 0
\end{align}

So you get either $b_2 = c_2  =0$ or $r_1 = r_2$. Last one would be a contradiction to the statement above. Therefore $b_2 = c_2  =0$ and $b$ and $c$ are real.

Comment: Note that saying "the Hint above" does not necessarily jive with the way the answers get ordered for a given user.  Better to list out the intended hint explicitly.

Answer (score 4):

Hint 1: Suppose you have a polynomial with two distinct real roots be labelled as $r_1,r_2$. How would you write this polynomial, and how does this compare with the form given?

Hint 2: Does multiplying or adding real numbers ever produce a complex number?

Answer (score 0):

$z=\dfrac{-b\pm\sqrt\Delta}{2}$, $\Delta=b^2-4c$. In order to have two real solutions you must have $\Delta\gt0$ and $b$ real. $c\in\mathbb{R}$, follows.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by others, in this context *complex constants* simply means *complex numbers.*

Hint to solve the problem: Try to use [Vieta's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Vieta.27s_formulas).

> $b=-z_1-z_2$
>  $c=z_1z_2$
>  where $z_{1,2}$ are the roots